# I don't understand element 103 from project Euler?

Tags: python

I am slowly solving my way though project Euler. I have reached [problem 103](https://projecteuler.net/problem=103) and I don't understand the criteria for the sets. The two rules given are (1), no two sets should have the same sum, (2), if a set has more elements than another, then its sum is higher as well. Under these two conditions, I would expect that these would be the optimal sums:

```
n=1:{1}
n=2:{1,2}
n=3:{1,2,3}
n=4:{1,2,3,4}
n=5:{1,2,3,4,5}
...
```

Where is my logic flawed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question states no subsets of the set can have the same sum, so in n=3, if we take the subsets `{1, 2}` and `{3}`, they have the same sum - 3.

I think you are comparing the whole sets against each other, while the question talks about subsets.

Answer (score 1):

They are asking

> any two non-empty disjoint subsets